# Converting VB6 procedure to SQL query -Unable find the error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to convert a `VB6` procedure to `SQL` query.

I am noob to **SQL** and finding little hard to find `ERROR` in the query in which I am trying to build.

Please guide:

```
    SELECT *
    FROM Vault
    WHERE (Vault.[Cheque No] Like "*" & [Forms]![frmClientSearch]![txtChqNo] & "*")      
        AND (([Forms]![frmClientSearch]![txtContractNumber] Is Null) OR (Vault.[Contract Number] Like "*" & [Forms]![frmClientSearch]![txtContractNumber] & "*" )) 
        AND  (([Forms]![frmClientSearch]![txtStartDate] is NULL ) OR (Vault.[Cheque Date] >=  [Forms]![frmClientSearch]![txtStartDate] )) 
        AND (([Forms]![frmClientSearch]![txtEndDate]  is NULL  ) OR (Vault.[Cheque Date] <=  [Forms]![frmClientSearch]![txtEndDate] ))
```

Tis is query which I am trying to run..This executes perfectly when date is not empty .But, when the date field is empty. I am getting exception or SQL gives a blank output.

Comment: I think you're missing a closing ). The last AND is followed by 3 ( and 2 ); just add another ) to match the ( immediately after the AND.

Comment: @simonatrcl : edited the post I see that with query with all fields entered I get the expected output. But, when date field is empty I see some random behaviour

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer: you can't convert a VB6 query that references application objects (e.g. [Forms]![frmClientSearch]![txtChqNo]) to a plain SQL Server query directly.

What you could do, is create either a stored procedure or a in-line table valued function and pass the values from the form as parameters.

A stored procedure could look like the following code snippet:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Vault_Select
(
    @txtContractNumber VARCHAR(30),
    @txtChqNo   VARCHAR(30),
    @txtStartDate DATETIME,
    @txtEndDate DATETIME
)
AS
SELECT *
FROM Vault
WHERE (Vault.[Contract Number] LIKE '%' + @txtContractNumber + '%')
    AND (@txtChqNo IS NULL OR Vault.[Cheque No] LIKE '%' + @txtChqNo + '%')
    AND (@txtStartDate IS NULL OR Vault.[Cheque Date] >= @txtStartDate)
    AND (@txtEndDate IS NULL OR Vault.[Cheque Date] <= @txtEndDate)
```

Calling the sproc:

```
EXEC dbo.Vault_Select ('Contract', 'ChqNo', '20140120','20141022')
```

All that's left to do is to call the sproc using the parameters from your original query.
Since this is a VB6 issue, I'm out of it ;-)

A few side notes:

What you're trying to do is a so called "catch-all query" that might lead to performance issues depending on the table size.

Furthermore, I'm wonderin why you have a column namend [Contract **Number**] but the data type is alphanumeric, obviously. Same for [Cheque **No**]... Edit: And if the data are numeric, why would a wildcard search being required?

Comment: edited the post I see that with query with all fields entered I get the expected output. But, when date field is empty I see some random behaviour

Comment: @Mohanss82: please remember, all we have to work with is what you've posted. Your comment doesn't make much sense. Please provide ready to use sample data together with the expected result as well as some sample daa that would lead to incorrect resuslts. Other than that we'd just be guessing....